# how to register external glassfish 3.1.2.2 on eclipse indigo 3.7.2 on mac 10.7.5

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, glassfish, glassfish-3

I want to register glassfish server 3.1.2.2 open source edition with my eclipse.

I am running

- Mac Lion 10.7.5 64 bit
- java version 1.6.0_37
- Eclipse indigo 3.7.3
- Glassfish 3.1.2.2 open source edition downloaded from 
  http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html
  I downloaded the file glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix-ml.sh then I ran it as executable file

  ```
  chmod u+x glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh 
  ./glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix.sh
  ```

the installation process finished successfully.

**Then I tries to install glassfish plugin:**

in eclipse go to server tab --> right click and new --> server --> download additional server adapter --> then I selected Oracle glassfish server tools and installed it 
(the photo below from windows but its only as example for my selection)

[image]

then I tried again from the server tab right click --> add --> server --> from glassfish node I selected glassfish server open source edition 3 (java EE 6) --> next --> browse to my glassfish installation directory.

It showing me this error when the defaut jre is selected, " **Missing classpath entry /0/it_stuff/servers/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar** "

and at the same wizard when I change it to MAC OS X default it give me another error  " **The specified directory is not a valid GlassFish installation, but contains a glassfish subdirectory which might be valid.** "

Any suggestions / solutions will be very appreciated  .....

UPDATE:
I found that its an old bug in Oracle glassfish tools but from mid 2011
http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-350?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel

Any clear workarounds ?

Comment: I have tried using this plugin dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/eclipse/indigo it installed Glassfish internal server, and worked successfully , but I still couldn't register the external glassfish open source server using the adapter as I described above ..... any solutions ??

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:

Glassfish server runtime requires full JDK instead of JRE. So click on Installed JRE preferences and add JDK by giving the JDK path.

Now, in your Glassfish server directory text box, give the full path "path/to/glassfish4/glassfish".(Note: look at the glassfish directory inside glassfish4)

Answer (score -1):

go to directory D:\softwares\eclipse\glassfish4\glassfish instead of just mentioning D:\softwares\eclipse\glassfish4

Comment: Is this answer not contained within the answer given by Logesh almost a year ago?